# Joint CDF of $X, Y$ dependent on $X$

Tags: statistics, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let X have a standard normal distribution and let $Y = 2X$. Determine whether (i) the cdf $F(x, y)$ of $(X,Y)$ is continuous, and (ii) the distribution of $(X, Y)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure in the $(x, y)$ plane.

I'm not sure how to approach (i), I understand that the joint cdf of continuous random variables is

$$
\iint f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
$$

but I'm not sure how to obtain $f(x, y)$ from the definitions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I posted this answer to the question about continuity:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607030/show-joint-cdf-is-continuous/2607146#2607146

Comment: As for absolute continuity, that's a lot simpler in this case. See my posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with continuous r.v. it is usually much more easy and clear to start working with their cdf, and that's actually what they ask for (not the density $f_{XY}$; in fact, you can't actually assume it exists).

Remember that the CDF is the real-valued function $F_{XY}$ that takes two real variables defined as
$$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\le x \wedge Y\le y)$$
that in this case can be reduced to
$$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\le x \wedge 2X\le y).$$

Then try to write an expression that relates this function to the (one variable) CDF of a normal standard r.v. (while there is not a nice formula for it you can just call it $\Phi(t)$ and all you need to know is that its derivative is the density function of $N(0,1)$ distribution.

Once you have a formula for $F_{XY}$ (which is not straightforward), you can see if it is a continuous function (this is equivalent to say thay $(X,Y)$ is a continuous r.v.) and if there is a function $f(x,y)\ge 0$ such that
$$F_{XY}(x,y)=\iint \limits_{\{(s,t)\colon s\le x,\,t\le y\}} f(s,t)\; d\mu.$$

When this is the case, such an $f$ is called a 'probability density function' and we say that $(X,Y)$ is an absolutely continuous r.v.

Not an easy one, but is possible if you use patience and detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still confused by how to use
$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\le x \wedge 2X\le y)$ and $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \int_{-\infty}^x e^\frac{-t^2}{2}dt$ to obtain a formula for $F_{XY}$.

Comment: Can you calculate, $P(X\le 2 \wedge  X \le 3)$? If you do it terms of $\phi(x)$ is okay.

Comment: Then, can you write an expression for $P(X\le s \wedge X \le t)$? Which cases for $(s,t)$ should you analyze?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate $P(X\le 2 \wedge X\le 3).$

Comment: I'm in a bit over my head with this, but I believe I could work backwards from a formula for $F_{XY}$ to understand it.

Comment: Instead of saying that *$X\le 2$ and $X \le 3$* (because $\wedge$ is the same as &)... couldn't you just abbreviate it and say...? Think.

Comment: I understand $P(X \le 2 \wedge X \le 3)$ is equivalent to $P(X \le 2)$, would I then just plug $t=2$ into the formula for $\Phi(x)$?

Comment: That's it! Then, for $P(X\le s, Y\le t)$ you have to check cases, let's say "(this) if $s\le t$ and (that) if $s>t$". To find $F_{XY}$ you have a pretty similar situation.

Comment: Is this on the right track? $$
\Phi(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\inf}^xe^\frac{-x^2}{2}dx, if x \le \frac{y}{2}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\inf}^xe^\frac{-y^2}{8}dx, if x > \frac{y}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Most answers posted to m.s.e. makes things more complicated than they need to be, but this answer does that quite a lot more than most.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607030/show-joint-cdf-is-continuous/2607146#2607146) showing the c.d.f. is continuous.

This is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on the plane, because the Lebesgue measure of the line $y=2x$ is $0,$ whereas this measure assigns the number $1$ to that set.